# Why do my internal hyperlinks not work in my notebook when creating them remotely?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I have quite a large jupyter notebook I'm working on in VScode, while using the high performance computing facility (connected through SSH).

I am trying to create some internal hyperlinks so I can jump from my table of contents to a specific section in the notebook. However, this does not work.

Code I'm using to create the link:

```
[Summary](#Summary)
some other cells
## Summary
```

It does create a link, but clicking on it does not work in VScode. This one keeps me right at the top of the notebook, other links to sections further down bring me to seemingly random cells down my file. Also, when opening the notebook in Github, clicking the link brings me back to the folder where my notebook is located.

The same construction does work both in a local jupyter instance, and in vscode, when not connected to the HPC.

One difference I can think of is that I use miniconda on the HPC, and the full anaconda installation locally.

Are the links not supported in miniconda? Or is it something else?

Comment: in markdown the generated id's are all lowercase with spaces replaced with `-`

Comment: I can't seem to repro with the same link and markdown title that you have listed, How large of a notebook do you have? Does it work fine for smaller notebooks? Your Python environment shouldn't affect this at all.

Comment: @aaron Thanks for your reply! My notebook is quite large, with 200+ cells. It does work fine in my small test notebook. I thought the key difference between the two would be that the small notebook was created and run locally, while the large one that I am actually using is loaded remotely. I had not considered the difference in size to be the deciding factor.